# Problem facing while adding \usepackage{orcidlink}

Tags: errors, overleaf

I am writing a document using TexStudio. The code is compiling fine except when adding a line `\usepackage{orcidlink}`. I am also adding one line in my original .tex file from where it will take all the authors' names and their orchid link details (pub658-arxiv_new_1.tex (see attached)). But it shows the following error.

```
**! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].**
```

```
\documentclass[aps,prd,twocolumn,
superscriptaddress,showpacs,preprintnumbers,amssymb]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{orcidlink}
\usepackage{graphicx}
.
.
.
\begin{document}
\title{}
\input{pub658-arxiv_new_1} %This file contains all the author's names as mentioned below.

\begin{abstract}


\end{abstract}
\maketitle 
.
.
.
.
.


\end{document}
```

---

```
   \noaffiliation
% \author{I.~Adachi\,\orcidlink{0000-0003-2287-0173}} % 2590
% \author{K.~Adamczyk\,\orcidlink{0000-0001-6208-0876}} % 2239
% \author{J.~K.~Ahn\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-5795-2243}} % 7423
  \author{S.~Maity\,\orcidlink{0000-0003-3076-9243}} % 2985
  \author{R.~Garg\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-7406-4707}} % 2213
  \author{S.~Bahinipati\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-3744-5332}} % 2332 
  \author{V.~Bhardwaj\,\orcidlink{0000-0001-8857-8621}} % 2228
  \author{H.~Aihara\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-1907-5964}} % 2223
  \author{S.~Al~Said\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-4895-3869}} % 6823
  \author{D.~M.~Asner\,\orcidlink{0000-0002-1586-5790}} % 4684
```

---

Comment: Showing just a fragment of code is not going to allow us to help you. Reduce the code to a complete minimal document that shows the error, and you'll probably be able to figure out what the problem is, but even if not, we need to see what you're doing.

Comment: I have tried to edit the question. Is that sufficient? I am being able to attach the entire file otherwise I would have done that.

Comment: This is better, thanks, but there's no need for the `\input`; just include a few representative lines in the sample document. But since your sample compiles without error, the chances are that you have a typo in one of your `\author` commands in the included file.

Comment: I see no mistake in writing \author commands.

Comment: But then your edit doesn't show the problem, so we're no further ahead.

Comment: And also in Overleaf online, it is fine. But in offline TeXstudio it is creating problems.

Comment: That's why I am asking any header file has to be added in the main tex file?

Comment: But your question makes absolutely no mention of that.

Comment: Is your local TexLive/MiKTeX installation up-to-date? Since `orcidlink` is relatively new.

Comment: I mentioned it does not compile if I add \usepackage{orcidlink}. Could you please suggest something if I want to get rid of this problem.

Comment: @SouvikMaity The document you showed compiles fine on my machine.

Comment: You've added a document that when we compile it, compiles without producing the error you are reporting. If that identical document produces the error on TeXStudio, then maybe as @lukeflo asks, your local TeX distribution is not up to date, in which case you should update it. If the document you've shown doesn't produce the error, then the problem is somewhere else in your actual document, and you need to start reducing it to find out where the actual problem lies.

Comment: TeXstudio 2.12.22 (Build: 2.12.22+debian-1build1)
Using Qt Version 5.12.8, compiled with Qt 5.12.5 R
..........I used this version

Comment: @egreg Could you please mention your version once?

Comment: TeXStudio is an editor, not a distribution.  The problem is a problem produced by LaTeX not by TeXStudio. @egreg and I use current TeXLive (2023).

Comment: @SouvikMaity the Tex version should be mentioned in the log file. Or you take a look into the directory where you installed it. The main directory always contains a year.

Comment: And I bet egreg runs an absolutley up-to-date version of TL2023 ;)

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.6.1)

Comment: I see it from log file and can see it's the 2019 version. Let me check with 2023 version.

Comment: 2019 might be to old. Run `kpsewhich orcidlink.sty` from your shell to test if the package is there.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked in on CTAN. `orcidlink` is only part of the official TeX distros since November 2020. Thus, TL 2019 is too old and that causes your problem. Install a new version. Since you're running Debian, I don't recommend installing TeXLive through `apt` because those packaged versions are never very up to date. Better install from tug directly using the perl installer.

Comment: +1 for the detective work. :) But then the error reported by the OP doesn't quite match, since one would expect "File not found" and undefined control sequence errors.

Comment: Thats right. But the MWE compiles fine with an up to date TL. So the `TeX capacity exceeded Error` might have nothing to do with the `orcidlink` package, but results from something else in the OPs main.text file that we cannot track...